# How to leave the Rename Printer dialogue without renaming the printer

Tags: catalina, printing

In Catalina, when I try to rename a printer but then change my mind and try to close out of the screen, one cannot.

Here's what I did:

- Go to rename an existing printer (System Preferences > Printers & Scanners > Right click > Rename Printer)
- When the rename printer dialog opens, then change your mind and don't rename the printer.
- Or, perhaps just rename the "Location" and leave the printer field the same.

For me, macOS Catalina always responds like this, **even when there is no other printer that has a conflicting name.**

[image: Printer error message]

Is there a way to cancel the `Rename Printer` dialogue once one enters it without renaming the printer? OR, if this problem does not show up on other people's computers when they try to replicate this problem, what might be causing my system to do this? This seems like one among many bugs in this frustrating release of the operating system.

Answer (score 1):

I tried and just like what you said, if you don't change the printer name then you can not change the location field neither.
Without renaming the printer, there are two situations:

1. The "Location" is not changed. Then just leave the dialogue by click the "Cancel" button.
2. The "Location" is changed. As far as I know, you have to rename the printer name then you can change the "Location".

Once entered the `Rename Printer` dialogue, you can always exit by clicking the "Cancel" button.